# In spacy if a word is tagged for different entity type then how to remove one entity type and its span?

Tags: python, list, tuples, spacy

Input:

```
[('PERSON1: thank you for calling ABCD my name is QWERT and him i speaking with PERSON2: hi QWERT this is QAZWSXE RFVTGB', {'entities': [(102, 116, 'PERSON'), (29, 33, 'ORG'), (45, 50, 'PERSON'), (45, 50, 'ORG')]})]
```

Here, say "QWERT" is tagged as (45, 50, 'PERSON') and (45, 50, 'ORG') so we need to remove the second entity type and its span (45, 50, 'ORG')
Note: In this example, we have 4 entity types and their span but this number will vary

Expected result:

```
[('PERSON1: thank you for calling ABCD my name is QWERT and him i speaking with PERSON2: hi QWERT this is QAZWSXE RFVTGB', {'entities': [(102, 116, 'PERSON'), (29, 33, 'ORG'), (45, 50, 'PERSON')]})]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try to assign a conflicting annotation you'll get an exception, so you can use this code to just keep the first annotation. If you want to keep the second annotation instead you'll have to figure out how to assign them in order of priority, you didn't explain how you know you want the second one so I'll leave that up to you.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("en")

# put your data here
data = ...
cleaned = []

for text, annotations in data:
    ents = annotations["entities"]
    doc = nlp(text)
    for start, end, label in ents:
        try:
            span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label)
            if span:
                doc.ents = doc.ents + (span,)
        except:
            # if it overlaps we'll get an exception
            print("skipping:", start, end, label)
    out_ents = [(ss.start, ss.end, ss.label) for ss in doc.ents]
    cleaned.append( (text, {"entities": out_ents}) )

print(cleaned)
```

Note this doesn't really work with the example data you gave because all your character offsets are off, so it's impossible to get valid spans.